# Jmeter test failed with only 5 thread

Tags: jmeter

I am new into Jmeter and trying to do my first load test, When I get my data from website it is always come in .txt form and when this data I try to run my test it fails, [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is wrong without seeing the "Sampler result" tab screenshot for at least one failed sampler.

Going forward consider providing as much information as you can, i.e.:

- Screenshot of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- Screenshot of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener demonstrating Sampler result, request data and headers and response data
- At least relevant parts of the *jmeter.log* file, better with the [debug logging for the test elements involved enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)